# How to call the Route Name in Html.ActionLink asp.net MVC?

Tags: routes, html.actionlink

I have this route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ViewGames",     // Route name
    "psp/{controller}/{action}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Games"}  // Parameter defaults
);
```

and I used `<%= Html.ActionLink("God of War", "godofwar", "Games")%>` all though it gives me a link like this `somesite.com/psp/games/godofwar/` but the other link became also like that for example my homecontroller became this `somesite.com/psp/home/about/`?

how can call the routename so other won't have the ViewGames route?

I dont want to try this `<a href="/psp/games/godofwar/">` which is not good.. .

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You explicitly call a route using

```
<%: Html.RouteLink("link_text", "route_name", route_parameters) %>
```

All the overloads for Html.RouteLink are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.routelink.aspx)

Comment: are you sure? the first parameter for RouteLink is the anchor text and the second is route name... so: Html.RouteLink("link_text", "route_name", route_parameters)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Why doesn't Microsoft provide a textual description of what the method does in their documentation? It gives all the overloads but the overloads of what? What does it do? Hopefully someone at MS reads this!